# Координаты областей РФ

Tags: google-maps-api, геолокация, google-geocoding-api

Заметил у Гугла очень нужную штуку - он знает координаты границ практически всех областей/городов РФ.

Но, увы, выдрать оттуда их нельзя - границы рисуюися прям на картинках, а времени (да и желания) парсить картинки нет.

Скажите, есть ли какое-то общедоступный справочник полигонов областей-городов РФ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот тут гляньте:

[Свободные данные по границам субъектов РФ](http://gis-lab.info/qa/rusbounds-rosreestr.html)

и тут:

[Данные OpenStreetMap в форматах XML и PBF](http://gis-lab.info/projects/osm_dump/) - если вы умеете работать с *.osm файлами, то для вас не составит труда вытащить нужные отношения. Подробная информация...

**UPD:** [Вот ещё есть](http://www.gadm.org/country) глобальная база данных по границам. Там данные различного уровня детализации по административным и государственным границам в разных форматах (включая Google Earth kml).

Answer (score 2):

Если кому-то требуются координаты в формате [JSON](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjN2ZTH0L3XAhVFYZoKHbRkAToQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJSON&usg=AOvVaw1Df6AuBflWC5QVLBzpdCio), есть [готовый](https://gist.github.com/max107/6571147) на GitHubGist (сервис обмена фрагментами кода). Разумеется, там огромное кол-во строк и привести здесь не представляется разумным.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/212762)

Comment: @0xdb, Ep1demic Автор вопроса запросил ссылку (т.е. оффтопик для ruSO на данный момент), ссылку и получил. Вы действительно считаете, что этот ответ можно улучшить?

Comment: @Ep1demic см.комментарий выше

Comment: @4per а Вы посмотрите на ответ, данный ранее и этот и решите, даже сами для себя, какой из этих ответов лучше?

Comment: @Ep1demic вы про оформление или кол-во ссылок?

Comment: @4per Позитивно подходя, улучшить можно всё. В данном случае вопрос спорный и не стоит заострять внимание.

Comment: @4per про оформление естественно

Comment: @Ep1demic отправил улучшающую правку на экспертную проверку :)